# Comment dit-on « Is it not correct that you were here yesterday? » en français ?

Tags: négation, subordonnées

Je voudrais savoir quelle est la traduction de la phrase suivante :

> **Is it not correct that** you were here yesterday?

La traduction "Google" ne donne pas une bonne traduction. Google propose :

> Est-il (pas) exact que (...)

Puis-je dire : « Est-il pas exact que (...) »?

Comment: Et que proposes-tu comme traduction ? French Language ne fait pas de traduction (voir le [help Centre](http://french.stackexchange.com/help)) mais si tu en proposes une en disant ce qui te poses problème on te répondra.

Comment: @Laure je ne sais pas vraiment. Vous pouvez dire que je cherche une phrase française classique qui donne le signification de "Is it not correct that ...". Et s'il y a aucun telle phrase, je cherche une phrase française commun qui exprime le signification d'une phrase comme: "Is it not correct that you were here yesterday?"

Comment: Essayez de proposer votre idée en disant ce qui vous gêne... ou par exemple donnez la traduction de google et dites pourquoi vous pensez que ce n'est pas bon.

Comment: @Laure d'accord. Je vais le faire immédiatement.

Comment: @Laure je suis imbécile. J'écrivais: "Is it correct that (...)" et le traduction a  été proposé: "Est-il exact que (...)". Quelle erreur. D'ailleurs, puis-je dis: "**Est-il pas exact que** (...)"?

Comment: @Quelqu'un En fait, Google donne "Est-il exact" même si vous écrivez "Is it not correct". J'ai ajouté cela dans votre question, vous pouvez la compléter en indiquant pourquoi la traduction Google vous semble fausse peut-être ? C'est toujours intéressant de comprendre votre réflexion :)

Comment: @Random I am going to talk in English because I'll find it difficult to explain in French what is happening exactly. I was pretty sure that I typed "Is it not correct that" into Google translate and that it gave me "Est-il exact". After Laure proposed that I write what Google gave, I wrote "Is it not correct that" again to make sure, but this time it did give me: "Est-il pas exact". So I thought that I must have written "Is it correct that" at the first time

Comment: @Quelqu'un J'ai également eu cette situation. En éditant votre question, j'ai regardé la traduction Google, et je suis presque certain d'avoir vu "Est-il correct", alors qu'en réessayant maintenant, la traduction est "Est-il pas correct"...

Comment: Google traduction évolue en fonction de ce qu'il trouve sur le web et peut effectivement donner des traductions différentes d'un jour à l'autre (les utilisateur peuvent également proposer leurs traductions il me semble). Pour ce qui est de la traduction: **"N'est-il pas correct/exact"** plutôt que **"Est-il pas correct/exact"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it not [...] ?

donne en français:

> N'est-il pas [...] ?

Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait de plus juste traduction.

Avec votre exemple:

> N'est-il pas exact* que vous étiez là hier ?

**vrai* and *correct* could be alternatives for *exact*

**EDIT en prenant en compte le commentaire de @jlliagre:**

*"N'est-il pas exact"* est une formulation formelle, dans un registre courant on dirait plutôt:

En formes déclaratives (très utilisées en langage courant):

> C'est pas vrai que vous étiez là hier ?

ou

> Pas vrai que vous étiez là hier ?

En formes interrogatives (registre courant qui tend vers le soutenu)

> Vous étiez là hier, n'est-ce pas ?

ou

> Vous étiez là hier, pas vrai ?

Comment: Note that `n'est-il pas exact` is quite formal. In spoken informal French, you are more likely to hear: `C'est pas vrai que tu étais là hier ? / C'est pas vrai que que vous étiez là hier ?`